# Making a terminal executable file that changes the date on your Mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

If we go to `SystemPreferences > date and time`, we can change the date of our mac. Can you create a terminal-executable program that changes the date when I open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the date of the  mac using the following command from the terminal.

```
date -u {month}{day}{hour}{minute}{year}
```

Replaced bracket with a two digit number. To set, October 16th 2020 21:16 would become the following command:

```
date 1016211620
```

Or you can create apple script to do it:

```
set ntpdPID to do shell script "systemsetup -getusingnetworktime; exit 0" with administrator privileges
if ntpdPID is "Network Time: On" then
    do shell script "systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off" with administrator privileges
    do shell script "systemsetup -setdate '01:24:1984' -settime '03:00:00'" with administrator privileges
else
    do shell script "systemsetup -setusingnetworktime on" with administrator privileges
end if
```

To create an apple script, see this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CreateaScript.html)

Comment: Is there a terminal command to set date to 'today'?

Comment: `sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com` will set the date and time to current day and time.